# Jmeter non-gui mode reporting : how to print the request and response of the api?

Tags: jmeter

I am using JMeter with non-GUI mode. I have one issue using its reporting. Currently, I am trying to generate the report but has the issue of request and response for the particular API.

I have used 2 HTML reports -

1. Generated from CSV - this report only gives me the status codes of the API with its URL's PFB screenshot -

[image]

2. Ant report generated from jtl/xml - this report only gives me the status codes for the API with its URL's PFB screenshot -

[image]

Is there any way by which I can get the all details around API like -

1. request headers
2. response headers
3. request data
4. response data

Answer (score 0):

I'm not aware of any existing approaches to get the information you need into HTML reports, the options are in:

1. Amend JMeter source code and the [report-template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/tree/rel/v5.4/bin/report-template) to include the information you're looking for, it's applicable for [HTML Reporting Dashboard](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/generating-dashboard.html)
2. Amend [Result File Configuration](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/properties_reference.html#results_file_config) and [XSLT template](https://github.com/apache/jmeter/blob/rel/v5.4/extras/jmeter-results-detail-report_21.xsl) to include the information you're looking for, it's applicable for [JMeter Ant Task](https://github.com/jfifield/ant-jmeter)
3. This one is most probably the easiest, you can use [Flexible File Writer plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/using-the-jmeter-flexible-file-writer-plugin) to write request and response headers and data into a separate file in an arbitrary format (it could also be HTML)